# How do I pass an argument along with docker-compose up?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file and in the terminal I am `typing docker-compose up [something]` but I would also like to pass an argument to `docker-compose.yml`. Is this possible? I've read about interpolation variables and tried to specify a variable in the `.yml` file using `${testval}` and then `docker-compose up [something] var="test"` but I receive the following error:

> WARNING: The testval variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
>   ERROR: No such service: `testval=test`

Answer (score 31):

Based on [dnephin answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35093256/how-do-i-pass-an-argument-along-with-docker-compose-up/35107585#35107585), I created this [sample repo](https://github.com/RafaelDelboni/docker-koa-mongo-nodemon) that you can pass an variable to docker-compose up.

The usage is simple:

MAC / LINUX

- `TEST= docker-compose up` to create and start both `app` and `db` container. The api should then be running on your docker daemon on port 3030.
- `TEST=DO docker-compose up` to create and start both `app` and `db` container. The api should execute the `npm run test` inside the `package.json` file.

WINDOWS (Powershell)

- `$env:TEST="";docker-compose up` to create and start both `app` and `db` container. The api should then be running on your docker daemon on port 3030.
- `$env:TEST="do";docker-compose up` to create and start both `app` and `db` container. The api should execute the `npm run test` inside the `package.json` file.

Answer (score 23):

You need to ensure 2 things:

1. The `docker-compose.yml` has the environment variable declared. For example,

```
services:
    app:
        image: python3.7
        environment:
            - "SECRET_KEY=${SECRET_KEY}"
```

2. have the variable available in the environment when `docker-compose up` is called:

```
SECRET_KEY="not a secret" docker-compose up
```

Note that this is not equivalent to pass them during build, as it is not advisable to store secrets in docker images.

Comment: Beware of terminal environment variables. They might replace some of your arguments that are passed to dockerfile from docker-compose and result in unexpected argument variables during build

Answer (score 16):

You need to pass the variables as environment variables:

```
testvar=test docker-compose up ...
```

or

```
export testvar=test
docker-compose up
```

Comment: It is not what we are looking for. Host environment values are not copied to container even when set in composer file in environment section. If build variables have to be set then build section of composer file has to be used. I will publish it in the response

Comment: so helpful your answer dude!

Answer (score 4):

From the docs:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/

https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/build/

You can't pass arguments to docker-compose up, but you can pass arguments to docker-compose build:

`docker-compose build --build-arg KEY1=VALUE1 --build-arg KEY2=VALUE2`

Comment: the question is about arguments to pass to  'docker-compose up' , no 'docker-compose build'

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you want to do here, but if what you need is to pass an environmental variable to a specific container docker-compose.yml allows you to do that:

```
web:
  ...
  environment:
    - RAILS_ENV=production
    - VIRTUAL_HOST=www.example.com
    - VIRTUAL_PORT=3011
```

This variables will be specific for the container you specified them to, and wil not be shared between containers.

Also "docker-compose up" doesn't take any argument.

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with build argumenets please declare them in compose yml file as follows

```
services:
  app: (name of service
    build:
      context: docker/app/ (where is your docker build root)
      dockerfile: Dockerfile (that is optional)
      args:
        - COMPOSER_AUTH_TOKEN (name of variable, value will be taken from host environment)
```

Well before running docker-compose up, export variable as other guys suggested. It will work. I tried. Use docker compose version 3 and above. Have fun

Comment: how would i pass something like this to docker using a docker-compose file:  '--shm-size=10.24gb'

Answer (score 0):

Compose supports declaring default environment variables in an environment file named `.env` placed in the project directory.

Step 1:
Create a file named `.env` in the project directory

Step 2:
Declare variables in the form `VAR=VAL`

NOTE: There is no special handling of quotation mark i.e. `TESTVAL='test'` means `TESTVAL is 'test'`(with quotation mark) and not just `test`. So you'd declare it as `TESTVAL=test`.

Step 3:
Use the variables in the Compose file as:

```
environment:
  myval=${TESTVAL}
```

Documentation: [Declare default environment variables in file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/)

BONUS: If you are building image on the fly in you `docker-compose.yaml`, then you can even pass the `build args` using environment variables. Eg:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  myapp:
    build:
      context: ./myDir
      dockerfile: ./myDir/myDockerfile
      args:
      - MYARG=${TESTVAL}
```

Comment: how would i pass something like this from docker-compose to docker run:   '--shm-size=10.24gb'

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to find solution for batch file, based on [Rafael Delboni answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40441844/4434423) you can add command inside batch file for calling powershell:

```
powershell $env:TEST="";docker-compose up ...
```

but instead of that because it's expensive to call powershell inside batch file you can initialize TEST variable inside batch file and then call your docker-compose command.
Something like this:

```
set TEST = ...
docker compose up ...
```