# Pass argument to docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In my docker compose file there is a dynamic field which I'd like to generate during the running. Actually it is a string template:

```
environment:
    - SERVER_URL:https://0.0.0.0:${PORT}
```

And I want to configure this `PORT` parameter dynamically

```
docker-compose run <service> PORT=443
```

In [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/) there is `ARGS` parameters set I suppose I can use. But there is no information how can I use those inside compose file

Comment: have a look at https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#compose-documentation it seems to answer your question

Comment: this is solution is by environment variables. I want to use command line arguments instead

Comment: Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35796353/can-i-pass-arguments-into-docker-compose-the-command-config-option?answertab=active#tab-top) and its comments.

Comment: I believe what OP requires is to be able to pass a value starting from docker-compose call. Try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35093256/how-do-i-pass-an-argument-along-with-docker-compose-up

Comment: It's possible to use an environment variable in docker-compose. It's a bit different that what i initially thought but works

For more: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

Comment: The `ARGS` you refer to are arguments to `COMMAND`.  It isn't anything that would be interpreted as arguments by `docker-compose run`.

Comment: Very simple to do.  See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62123142/1025695

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is possible with [docker stack deploy](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stack_deploy/)

Example Compose File in your environment section:

```
- MY_VARIABLE_NAME=${MY_VARIABLE_VALUE}
```

Stack Deploy Command (I ran this from Gitbash in Windows):

```
MY_VARIABLE_VALUE=some-value docker stack deploy --compose-file compose_file_here stackname
```

**Reference**
See this Github post [here](https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/735)

Comment: Worth noting that this works with `docker compose up` as well

Comment: All of these answers boil down to environment variables. Too bad one can't pass an argument to `docker-compose up` in such a way that the variable would be expanded when "executing" the docker compose, but would NOT be seen by the container. For example, a variable that specifies which version of the image to use to spin up a particular service.

Answer (score 67):

In docker-compose, arguments are available and usefull only in `dockerfile`. You can specify what you are doing in the level ahead like following:

```
#dockerfile
ARG PORT
ENV SERVER_URL "https://0.0.0.0:$PORT"
```

Your port can be set in your docker-compose.yml:

```
build:
  context: .
  args:
    - PORT=443
```

It is actually an environment variable in any case. You can pass it through your run command if that fits to you:

```
PORT=443 docker-compose run <service>
#or
docker-compose run <service> -e PORT=443
```

Comment: This sucks, I want to be able to download a pre-built container and run it with whatever runtime arguments I choose. Being able to list them in docker-compose should be basic functionality. I'll just override the entrypoint.

Comment: @Dagrooms I think this is possible with stack deploy. See my answer.

Comment: This worked for me and I did not have to touch my Dockerfile.  I used `PORT=443 docker-compose ... -f bla.yml` to pass the port in and then in my YAML file, the line `command: bash -c "echo $PORT"` successfully displayed 443.

Comment: This does not seem to work anymore, unfortunately.
- When using `MYARG=123 docker-compose run <service>`, it returns "The terum MYARG=12345 is not recognized as a cmdlet name, function, script file or operating program."
- When using `docker-compose run <service> -e MYARG=123`, it returns "Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "-e": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown"

Comment: The answer by @mareoraft worked perfectly and is the cleanest option imo. I think it should be turned into an actual answer so it doesn't get easily overlooked!

Answer (score 62):

You can use the flag when using docker-compose build

```
docker-compose build --build-arg PRODUCTION=VALUE
```

In Dockerfile you can get the argument PRODUCTION

```
# Dockerfile
ARG PRODUCTION
FROM node:latest
```

Comment: Not exactly what was asked originally, but you helped me a lot for the build stage.

Answer (score 7):

Sharing the only way I managed to set a runtime variable with Docker Compose using minimum setup and command changes.

On `docker-compose.yml`:

```
services:
  my_service:
    ...
    environment:
      - MYENVVAR=placeholder_value
```

On the terminal:

```
docker-compose run -e MYENVVAR=actual_value my_service
```

Please pay attention that the "-e" portion of the command line argument must come before the service name.

This is described on the official documentation: [Set environment variables with docker compose run](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#set-environment-variables-with-docker-compose-run)

Comment: Great answer. $ docker-compose up -e MYENVVAR=actual_value my_service doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me and I did not have to touch my Dockerfile:

I used

```
PORT=443 docker-compose ...(whatever)... -f bla.yml
```

to pass the port in and then in my YAML file, the line `command: bash -c "echo $PORT"` successfully displayed `443`.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with docker-compose with ARGS inside Dockerfile.

Problem to Solve:

- Pull changes from Git Respository, to Automate App Deploy

Dockerfile

```
RUN 
ARG CACHEBUST=1 # This will setup a arg called CACHEBUST
RUN  git clone
```

Run the below bash command to build and run. SETTING --build-arg CACHEBUST= random md5sum hash, makes Docker-Compose to rebuild the image, starting the line with ARGS and so on.

```
docker-compose -f dockerprd.yml build  --build-arg CACHEBUST=$(echo $RANDOM | md5sum | head -c 20; echo;) && docker-compose -f dockerprd.yml up -d
```

Answer (score 1):

We can pass the argument to docker compose like that:
Run the `docker-compose.yaml` with this command:

```bash
$ ENV=staging docker-compose up
```

`docker-compose.yaml` file look like that:

```yaml
...
go:
    container_name: mailavail_go
    build:
      context: ./go
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        ENV: ${ENV} # we can defined arguments like that
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
...
```

`Dockerfile` file look like that:

```yaml
...
FROM golang:latest

ARG ENV=dev # we can also add a default value

ENV ENV=${ENV} # this will set the value

echo "My ENV is ${ENV}" # This is for testing purpose and it will the ENV value

RUN mkdir /golang
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I found for this problem was to dynamically create an env file and pass it as --env-file value.

I created a bash script:

```
$PROJ=$1
echo "REST_URL=http://$2" > ./docker-env-$PROJ
echo "BRANCH=$3" >> ./docker-env-$PROJ

docker compose \
      -p $PROJ \
      --env-file ./docker-env-$PROJ \
      up -d

rm -f ./docker-env-$PROJ
```

and run it:

`start_all.sh mycont "localhost:8080" master`

Answer (score 0):

To use variables in a docker-compose.yml or compose.yml file you can do this:

1. Reference the variable in the file `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'

name: "my_project"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:$docker_image_version # <- this is the variable
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example
```

2. Define a `.env` file in the same directory as `docker-compose.yml`:

```bash
# .env
docker_image_version="16-alpine3.19"
```

3. Check that the variables are correctly replaced:

```bash
docker compose config
```

You should see that the variable will be replaced:

```bash
name: my_project
services:
  db:
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example
    image: postgres:16-alpine3.19
    networks:
      default: null
    restart: always
networks:
  default:
    name: my_project_default
```

4. Start the containers;

```bash
docker compose up -d
```

5. Check the running containers:

```bash
docker compose ps
```

You should see something like:

```bash
NAME              IMAGE                    COMMAND                           SERVICE   CREATED         STATUS         PORTS
my_project-db-1   postgres:16-alpine3.19   "docker-entrypoint.sh postgres"   db        5 seconds ago   Up 5 seconds   5432/tcp
```

In the output you can see that it is running the version set in the `.env` file: `16-alpine3.19`

Source: [Docker compose documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/#substitute-with-an-env-file)