# How to pass start args to docker compose file like docker run --opts?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have write a docker compose file, I want to start compose use

```
docker-compose up -d
```

But I want to pass args to my images 
It look like

```
docker run --security-opt=seccomp:unconfined mysql:8.0
```

But I find compose file only have basic config such as `network`, `volume`, `environment`

My compose file

```
db:
image: mysql:8.0
container_name: onlinecodedb
volumes:
  - onlinecode-database:/var/lib/mysql
environment:
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mysqlrootpassword
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: mysqlpassword
  MYSQL_USER: mysql
  MYSQL_DATABASE: onlinecode
ports:
  - "3300:3306"
networks:
  - onlinecode-net
```

How I solve this problem?

Comment: I think its already posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43544328/pass-argument-to-docker-compose)

Comment: @ArunKumarGR I don't think so, it use in dockerfile build time, But I already have built image, just want to run it. There are some many opts in `docker run` but docker-compose only basis options

Comment: Have you read the [Compose file reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/)?

Comment: @DavidMaze yes, But I think you should give me a solution or tell me where the specific part of the document you are referring to, instead of asking me if I have read it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the `docker run` options have matching [Docker Compose options](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/).  In particular, `docker run --security-opt` maps to a [`security_opt:` field](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#security_opt).

```
db:
  image: 'mysql:8.0'
  security_opt:
    - 'seccomp:unconfined'
  et: cetera
```