# Passing arguments to a docker container when calling docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

my intention is to able to pass some arguments to a docker container when calling the docker-compose for that container.

Something like

```
docker-compose up -d myContainer myArg1=hallo myArg2=world
```

My Docker file looks something like:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:2.2 AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY Myproj/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1 .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myproj.dll", myArg1, myArg2]
```

And the docker-compose.yml file looks like this:

```
version: '3.4'

services:

   myContainer:
      image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}myContainerImage
      build:
         context: ../..
         dockerfile: MyProj/Dockerfile
```

First of all I wonder if this is something doable and secondly how to do it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass argument to docker compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43544328/pass-argument-to-docker-compose)

Answer (score 13):

There are two "halves" to the command line Docker ultimately runs, the [entrypoint](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/#entrypoint) and the [command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/#cmd).  There are corresponding Docker Compose [`entrypoint:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#entrypoint) and [`command:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#command) directives to set them.  Their [interaction](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact) is fairly straightforward: they're just concatenated together to produce a single command line.

Given what you show, in your Dockerfile you could write

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myproj.dll"]
```

and then in your `docker-compose.yml`

```
command: myArg1=hallo myArg2=world
```

and that would ultimately launch that process with those arguments.

If you want to be able to specify this from the command line when you spin up the Compose stack, [Compose supports `${VARIABLE}` references everywhere](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution) so you could write something like

```
command: myArg1=${MY_ARG1:-hallo} world
```

and then launch this with a command like

```
MY_ARG1=greetings docker-compose up
```

A very typical pattern in Docker is to use `ENTRYPOINT` for a wrapper script that does some first-time setup, and then runs the command as the main container process with `exec "$@"`.  The entrypoint gets the command-line arguments as parameters and can do whatever it likes with them, including reformatting them or ignoring them entirely, and you could also use this to implement @Kevin's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59318743/10008173) of configuring this primarily with environment variables, but translating that back to `var=value` type options.

Comment: what should I use in the command line ? If I write "MY_ARG1=greetings docker-compose up" it won't work. The command line should being with docker-compose.

Comment: Do you need to be able to specify the arguments every time you run `docker-compose up`, or is including it in the YAML file enough?

Comment: specify them everytime

Comment: [`docker-compose up`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/) doesn't take parameters in the syntax you show in the question, so the only way to pass them in like this is using environment variables.  If you need to explicitly specify the entire command line, Docker Compose is a little bit of a mismatch for your needs and a plain `docker run` might work better (or even just run the tool outside of Docker).

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use environnement variables, you can launch your command with it.

Something like this: (there are several ways to do this)

In compose:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

```
environment:
- myVar
```

In dockerfile:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myproj.dll", "$myVar"]
```