# How to evaluate a dynamic variable in a docker-compose.yml file?

Tags: bash, docker, date, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want to suffix a file name with the current date in my `docker-compose.yml` file. The end goal being a file such as `my_log_123456789.log`, where `123456789` is the current unix date.

I tried using an `.env` file, but that did not evaluate as expected. My attempt was:

```
# .env
NOW="$(date +%s)"
```

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'
services:
  xxx:
      container_name: xxx
      image: xxx/xxx
      volumes:
        - /home/ubuntu/xxx_"$(NOW)".log:/home/ubuntu/xxx.log
      ...
```

I tried a few variations of this and had the following issues:

- `ERROR: Invalid interpolation format for "volumes" option in service "xxx": "/home/ubuntu/xxx_$(NOW).log:/home/ubuntu/xxx.log"`
- A directory was created that was named `'xxx_"$(date +%s)".log'`

How can I append the current date to a log file in a `docker-compose.yml` file?

Comment: You can pass environment variables to `docker-compose run -e VAR=VAL`.

Comment: No, you can't..

Comment: Can you export the variable from your environment before running the Compose file? i.e. take `NOW` out of `.env`

Comment: Running `NOW="$(date +%s)" sudo docker-compose up -d` produces a directory `xxx_NOW.log/`

Comment: @KamilCuk, yes, yes you can. https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

Comment: The problem is that I am unable to _evaluate_ the `date +%s`. 

If I pass it in as an env var, it never gets evaluated. How would you define it in the `docker-compose.yml` file?

Comment: Looks like this might be the way to go. I will give this a try: https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/6303#issuecomment-406869938

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you can do is to generate `.env` just before calling `docker-compose`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cat << EOF > .env
NOW=$(date +%s)
EOF

docker-compose up
```

Answer (score 6):

No, docker doesn't have a "dynamic" variable - the text from `--env-file` is read by docker [as it is](https://github.com/milindchawre/docker/blob/a4fdf74b52d0a804da1b18d3f573fe2aec1ad28e/runconfig/opts/envfile.go#L38), literally, leading and trailing `'` or `"` are removed, without any interpretation and expansions done by shell.

Create another script that will `export` the variable value to `docker-compose` or will edit the content of your variable in your `.env` file before calling `docker-compose`.