# How to set random string as env variable in docker compose

Tags: docker-compose, yaml

I tried following things but I get `ERROR:Invalid interpolation format for "environment" option in service`

```
version: '3.9'
services:

  service-1:
    image: library/python:3.8
    environment:
      - VAR1=$(head -c 12 /dev/random | base64)
      - VAR2={{ randAlphaNum 16 | b64enc }}
    command: >
      bash -c "export VAR3=$(uuidgen)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a `.env` file with needed variables.

```bash
VAR1=test
VAR2=16
```

And forward them inside the container in `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: '3.9'
services:

  service-1:
    image: library/python:3.8
    environment:
      - VAR1=${VAR1}
      - VAR2=${VAR2}
    command: >
      echo $VAR1 # works
```

NB : You cannot run command in `.env` file.
If you really want to do it, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62123142/5391965)

Answer (score 0):

**.env**

```
VAR1=$(head -c 12 /dev/random | base64)
```

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
services:
  service1:
    image: ubuntu:latest
    container_name: sample_container1
    environment:
      - local_var1=$VAR1 #  doesnt work
      - local_var2=${VAR1} # doesnt work
      - local_var4=$$VAR1 # doesnt work
    command: >
      bash -c " export local_var3=$VAR1 # doesnt work
      && echo $local_var3 # doesnt work
      && echo $local_var4 # doesnt work
      && echo $VAR1 # works
      && echo VAR1=$VAR1  # works"

# each time we call $VAR1 we will get a new random string.
```