# Docker pass dynamic directory name to WORKDIR

Tags: python, docker

I have python project and trying to dockerize it. The usecase is as below
User create a parent directory eg `titanic` and checkout the `github repo`.
The project structure becomes like this

- titanic/

  - src/
  - Dockerfile
  - docker-compose.yml
  - .env

Now what I need is, to pass this parent directory name to `docker's WORKDIR Command` to create docker image.

In Dockerfile I have, `WORKDIR $PROJ_WORKDIR`

I tried many different ways to pass the directory name, but it always fails

```
1.    environment:
      - PROJ_WORKDIR=titanic
```

```
2. In .env, PROJ_WORKDIR=titanic
```

```
3. In docker-compose, args: 
                    - PROJ_WORKDIR=titanic
```

```
4. In Dockerfile, ENV PROJ_WORKDIR=some_default
```

Is there a way to configure and access it.

Comment: Try: `WORKDIR ${PROJ_WORKDIR}`

Comment: Normally your image should only contain one application, and it can't be change after it's built.  Using a fixed directory name like `/app` should be fine.  I wouldn't try to set this via an environment variable or make it configurable at all.

Comment: Hi David, Thanks. I agree with you but I needed it, in perspective of general user usage who have `.env` file to configure the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost there but just one syntax error:

Dockerfile will have entry as follows:

```
WORKDIR /app/${PROJ_WORKDIR}
```

Now this PROJ_WORKDIR can be set in numerous ways as pointed by you all the ways are valid.

More read about how to pass value to ARG variable:
[Pass argument to docker compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43544328/pass-argument-to-docker-compose)

Hope this helps, Thanks.